# Having trouble populating a variable range

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I have dabbled in vba for a little while, but its uses are mainly to save myself work and make easy things that are not easy to do in vanilla excel. I use SQL a lot and many things that are fascinatingly easy to get in SQL are surprisingly difficult in excel.

I recently made a new file to follow the costs that are generated when someone takes an item from our warehouse. Assuming that everything gets registered correctly I have made an SQL report that spits out different data; among which are pertinent to this question:

- An article number
- A cost centre

Now, I thought I would improve my file with some autogenerated lists, so I can use it for whatever department not just my own. The difference is that I know roughly the correct article numbers and cost centers of my department.

What I would like to do.

1. With a list of cost center numbers:
2. Generate a list of article numbers that are taken from the dump (~10.000 rows) that have been listed on each (specific) cost center. Unique, of course
3. Use the count of cost centers and the count of article numbers to copy formulas from a sheet with a template...
4. ...then populate the fresh sheet with the cost centers and article numbers. The formulas will then fetch with sumifs from the dump  and make nice monthly graphics of it all.

This is getting out of hand with the explanation, because I stranded pretty early doing this:

```
'-----------------------------------------------
Dim Myworkbook As Workbook
Set Myworkbook = ThisWorkbook
'-
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet3 As Worksheet
Dim Rgensheet As Worksheet
'-
Set Sheet1 = Myworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Sheet2 = Myworkbook.Sheets("00 Underlag")
Set Sheet3 = Myworkbook.Sheets("01 Dump")
Set Rgensheet = Myworkbook.Sheets("RGenInput")
'-
Dim Dump As Range
Set Dump = Sheet3.Range("A:M")
'------------------------------------------------
Dim antkat As Long
antkat = WorksheetFunction.Count(Rgensheet.Range("C:C"))
Dim kat As Range
Set kat = Myworkbook.Sheets("RGenInput").Range("C1:C" & antkat)
Dim kst As Long
kst = 242020

'To make matters easy I try to get the macro work for a single cost centre first...
'I plan to have a For-loop around that covers all of them, with the antkat variable


Dim artnos As Range
Dim artno As Long
Dim n As Integer
n = 1

For Each Row In Dump.Rows
If IsNumeric(Sheet3.Range("M" & Row.Row)) Then
    If Sheet3.Range("M" & Row.Row) = kst Then
        artno = Cells(Row.Row, 6)
        On Error Resume Next
        If IsError(Application.Match(artno, artnos, False)) Then
       ' I used the same code once to create a list of unique values from a huge list but I am unsure wether I can do this to a range that has no dimensions...
            Set artnos.Range(1, n).Value = artno
            n = n + 1
        End If
    End If
End If
Next Row
```

Now - this is ugly and very not up to my code standard but it has been a bigger project than what I normally do.

The question is twofold.

1. Is it possible to define a range variable that is completely flexible as to dimensions? This is what I am used to, you can just add rows to a variable table in sql like nothing but I am starting to think this is not possible the way I am trying to do it
2. Is this a reasonable way to execute the plan I made beforehand? If my code is to messy to read or the errors I make too many - can you please help me find a plan of execution or steps that can perform what I need? I can - with the help of google - figure out how to do the steps. That has worked for me in the past... =P

Comment: I have since learned that in order for a variable to contain a list, you really should define it as an array by adding a closed parenthesis to it. Maybe that will solve the problem. Will update if I get anywhere.

Comment: Good work Stian. Go ahead and answer your question (in the answer section) and accept it so others can learn from your situation. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, by chance, browsing through some microsoft help files. Who would have thought.

I was mistaken in thinking that a variable range can be used as **the array.** For future users having issues giving a variable several values - do read up on arrays which are defined by adding closed parentheses to your variable

```
Dim variable as integer
Dim variablearray() as integer
```